# ListView gets empty when back icon is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-lifecycle

I have two `activities`, in the main one I have a `text field` and two `buttons`, the user can enter text in the `text field`.

When clicking the add `button`,text will be added to some `ArrayList`.

When clicking show in list button a new activity with its own fragment should open showing a `listview` that contains the names that the user has entered.

I used `ArrayAdapter` and this is working fine. When I am in the list activity and when I click the *back button* of the device everything goes fine and the data in the `ArrayList` is not lost.
If I click show in list again I will find the old data I entered at the first time. But, if I click the **back icon** provided by Android at the top left of the device screen, the `ArrayList`becomes empty and when I click show in list the `listview` shows as empty.

Here is the main activity code,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ArrayList<String> itemList= new ArrayList<String>();


        final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_field);
        text.setHint("Enter name here");
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        Button showButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_button);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String name=  text.getText().toString();
                itemList.add(name);
                if (itemList.size()==1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name has been added to the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });

        showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("list", itemList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }//end oncreate
```

This is the ListActivity and its fragment code,

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static ArrayList <String> itemList;
    String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        itemList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);
         if (savedInstanceState==null){
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new list()).commit();
         }

    }

    public static class list extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
           ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

            ArrayAdapter <String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_main, R.id.row, itemList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;

        }
    }


}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? How can I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your List is getting cleared, i think problem is when you click on the actionbar back button, the main activity is getting called again or created again. Where you have nothing in your list.

Comment: How did you implemented the navigation from ListActivity to MainActivity ?

Comment: @Jitain Thank you for your answer, can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @dit I didn't implement any custom navigation from ListActivity to MainActivity, because that will be performed using back button. For navigation from MainActivity to ListActivity I have passed an intent that contains the ArrayList

Comment: Answer provided by the @Karthika is good, but leads to possible memory leaks for big apps. Rather what you can do, make your main activity single Instance or bring your old activity to foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a class Constantss.java and declare

```
public static ArrayList <String> itemList=null;
```

then inside your class

use

```
Constantss. itemList.add(name);
```

instead of

```
itemList.add(name);
```

// replace itemList with Constantss. itemList in all of your classes

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me how this will solve the problem? What mistake I have in the code? Thanks

Comment: @Dania a local arraylist(arraylist declared inside a class) won't keep the values in it always.So if it's made global static it can be used until you refresh the app(press exit/home button of the app).you can also avoid  intent.putExtra("list", itemList); if you are following this method you can just call Constantss.itemlist in the second class also instead of getting it from intent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, now my app is working properly. I have applied the global static variable concept you just explained in my MainActivity. So, instead of declaring it inside oncreate, I declared it as a static global variable. But, the list is showing properly even when I exit and reopen the app. Do static variables last even after I close the app? Thank you

Comment: @Dania it will exists until you clear it from task manager or you again run the app from your eclipse/studio.

Comment: Keep in mind. This is not the proper way. You can use it just for testing. Android may close your app since it requires more resources for an other app.

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me what is the proper way? Shall I have some storage like SQLite or files so that if my app gets closed, it can retrieve what was stored in its database after I open it again? Is this is the only way, or is there a better solution rather than using storage? Thanks

Comment: you can store it in a sharedpreference or sqlite database if you want to store it for next runs also(like login details of an app,like valuable data).If it's required just for one time run or page navigation the suggested method is ok...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a navigation issue. So you should close your ListActivity like this:

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //your code

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int itemID = item.getItemId();

        switch (itemID ) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Anyway your data can be lost if android destroys your MainActivity. So if you navigate from ListActivity back to MainActivity, MainActivity will be recreated and you data get lost. So you should find the way how to save your
data permanent.

there are two common ways:

1. Save data to data base (SQLite)
2. Save data to Preferences [How to store list of values in SharedPreferences](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/)