# How to restore the ListView and get Contents of List when back button in pressed?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

ActivityB --> Service class --> Populate ListView in ActivityC (as shown below and there is no fragment for it) ---> ActivityD

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    setLocale(pref.getString("myLocale", null));

    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_choose_number);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_number1);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(savedInstanceState != null ) {
        mobileNumbersList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("mobileNumbers");
    }
    mobileNumbersList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("mobileNumbers");

    mobileNumberAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.secnumsinglechoice,
            mobileNumbersList);

    numberListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNumberList);
    numberListView.setAdapter(numberAdapter);
    numberListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String numberChosen = numberAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent passNumberIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), US.class).
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, numberChosen);
            startActivity(passNumberIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Now when back button is pressed in ActivityD to ActivityC, I am getting null pointer error. I know the reason because this time, I am not passing the intent from ActivityD and ListView, adapter, data is all null.

So when I searched for how to save the state, I came across saveInstanceState, onRestoreInstance and onSaveInstance. But I am still not able to fix the issue. ActivityC doesn't have a fragment.

Comment: saveInstanceState is meant to restore the activity data when returning from background, its not related to forward or backward navigation, if your activity needs data from the previous activity, you should store it in a class field and check if its set before trying to read the intent data.

Comment: /What you meant by activity data ? The issue happening here is when I back navigate from ActivityD to ActivityC, I lose the activity C data.
Class field you mean like Intent ????

Comment: A class field is a variable declared directly on your class, store your ActivityC data inside a field on ActivityC so you can restore it if needed.

Comment: @Nanoc Yeah, Class variable tick worked like a charm. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29229401/3705478  Thanks. Power of "static" :)

Comment: But making a class level static variable, it shows a warning that static at class level is memory leak. And it also says security issues. But its a warning. Should I be worried?

Comment: As long as your not storing something really big you should not have any problem on modern android phones, try to set the variable to null once your not going to use the data anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should do:

- Check `getIntent()` is null or not. If it's not null, try to get data from it
- Put data into `savedInstanceState` variable on method `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: I tried putting data in savedInstanceState using onSaveInstanceState but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more detail of your activity C? Maybe, when you navigate back from activity D -> activity C, activity C jumps to onResume() because it hasn't been destroyed. Try to check you activity lifecycle in the logcat to see it.